# ArgumentError in Users#new First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing a ruby on rails tutorial and all of a sudden going to the signup page returns this:

[image]

Anyone know a fix? Or for that matter what went wrong? It seemed very sudden and I don't think I changed anything that would affect the signup page...

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                 :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

Comment: Please do NOT use a link to an image to show error text or code. Stack Overflow and Google can't search images, and, *when* that link breaks, your question will be pretty worthless.

Comment: It wouldn't let me. Not enough rep xD but thanks for doing it for me.

Comment: The problem remains, only the image is being displayed inline. That's not a lot of improvement.

Comment: Uh... well I dont know what your telling me to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that your `@user` object was not initialized..

You need to initialize your `@user` variable.  Here are a couple of options.

Make sure your `new` method initializes it in your `UsersController` class:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end
```

Another option is to just use a new object right in the form:

```
<%= form_for(User.new) do |f| %>
```

And yet another option, is to in your view, before echoing the `form_for`, put:

```
<% @user = User.new %>
```

My best recommendation would be to put the variable in the controller like I did in the first example.

Comment: My user controller looks like this:

Comment: class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

Comment: def create
    (at)user = User.new(user_params)
    if (at)user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                 :password_confirmation)
  end
end

Comment: there's your issue. you need a method in there named `new`.  paste my code that i put up there into your controller adjacent to `create` and `show`.

Comment: look at it again... there is a new method there.

Comment: i'm not seeing it.. edit your question with the controller code

Comment: The github repository is at https://github.com/torin555/sample_app. feel free to grab a copy and take a look.

Comment: and i'll say this again.. you need to have the `new` method in there. if you don't know what that means, then you need to go back to ruby 101.  Here is a gist.. copy and paste this code into your users controller. https://gist.github.com/ddavison/68b5e5052713af3e9458

Comment: Great. thanks that worked. And I would like to point out.... I sort of am on ruby 101. that's what this is. xD thanks though.

Comment: alrighty! cool, glad i helped you out.. if this question can be closed, go ahead and accept my answer